# Proving equations with respect to skew-symmetric matrix property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

suppose that R is a reflection matrix ($R^TR = I , det(R) = -1$) and $T_0$ is a vector and we have these equations:

$$
R' = R_0 R R_0^T ,\, T' = (I - R_0RR_0^T)T_0 \quad s.t  \quad R_0^TR_0 = I , det(R_0) = 1  
$$
$T_0$ is vector. now I proved part of it that it says
$R'T' = -T'$ , $\hat{T'}$ is skew-symmetric matrix of $T'$ vector . now I can't prove that $R'\hat{T'} = \hat{T'}R' = \hat{T'}$ and then I want to prove let $n = \frac{\hat{T'}}{\|\hat{T'}\|}$ then $R' = I - 2nn^T$

Can any one help me please? I need to prove this but I don't know how to handle $R'\hat{T'}$ ??

Comment: What do you mean by "$\hat T'$ is skew-symmetric matrix of $T'$"?. And perhaps it should be either $R' = R_0R^TR_0^T$ or $T' = (I - R_0R^TR_0^T)T_0$ instead of as you've given. Otherwise, I don't see that you could prove $R'T' = -T'$.

Comment: It is hat operator of $T'$ .I mean $$ \begin{array}(ccc) [0  & -t'_3 & t'_2  // t_3' & 0 & -t_1' // -t_2' & t_1' & 0] $$

Comment: This proved simply by producting two equations you menrioned!

Comment: No. First note that the equations I mentioned **are not the same** as the ones you gave. They are close, but there is a difference: In mine, you see $R^T$ where yours just have $R$. Second, you can no more prove it from my version *of both* equations than from your version. However if you replace ONE of your equations with the corresponding one of mine, then it can be proved. With your equations you end up with $R'T' = R_0RR_0^TT_0 - R_0RRR_0^TT_0$. All you've given is that $R^TR = I$. You have not given anything that guarantees $RR = I$.

Comment: FYI, [this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is very useful. The 2nd post explains matrices.